# Get github username by id

Tags: github, github-api

Using this link I can see that my (tonylampada) id on github is 218821
https://api.github.com/users/tonylampada

How could I do the opposite? Given the user id = 218821, what's the username?

---

Update

Answering nulltoken here because it's a long story and it won't fit in a comment.

[FreedomSponsors](http://www.freedomsponsors.org/) is a django application that uses django-social-auth to enable login with Github (and others).
(You should check it out, btw, please see the [about page](http://blog.freedomsponsors.org/about) in the blog :-)
Django-social-auth has a configuration flag that allows the application to store the github username on the database.
A few days ago I deployed a new version of FS with github login enabled, but with "storeGithubUsername" set to false.

A few users registered their github accounts, and now the database has their github ids, but not their usernames.

You can se in [my profile](http://www.freedomsponsors.org/core/user/2/tonylampada) that I have github as a "connected account" but there's no link to my github page.

I need it to make the link point to https://github.com/tonylampada

I'm ready to deploy a new version that fixes this, by setting the "storeGithubUsername" (that's not what it is called, I'm just simplifying here) to true.
But I'd like to patch the database with the already github-registered users. I have their github ids, but not their github usernames.

Comment: Why would you need this?

Comment: Long story... updated the question. Please, know the answer :o)

Comment: So I'm guessing there is no way to get the username from the id.. right?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

We need to do this on [Gitter](https://gitter.im) to deal with the situation where a user has changed their username on GitHub and we get a 404 response when querying their old username.

Here's an undocumented endpoint, so use as your own peril, but it does work for now.

Use the endpoint: `https://api.github.com/user/:id`, where `:id` is the ID of the user.

Similar endpoints exist for repos and orgs, at
`https://api.github.com/repositories/:id` and `https://api.github.com/organizations/:id` respectively.

Note that the new [repository redirects preview API](https://developer.github.com/changes/2015-04-17-preview-repository-redirects/) only supports repositories, not renamed users or organizations. In fact, the HTTP 301 redirect actually points to `https://api.github.com/repositories/:id`, so there's a good chance that these "ID" endpoints may in fact become official soon.

Comment: Thanks! I tested and it works. I updated this to be the correct answer.

Comment: It doesn't work anymore, at least it doesn't work at the time I'm writing.

Comment: Huh, never realized IDs were sequential.

Comment: It doesn't work, and it has become dangerous: GitHub now allows *logins* to be all digits, so this request returns unrelated users now.

Comment: Note the endpoint `https://api.github.com/user/:id` has API limits, I found this message in my network request: `{"message":"API rate limit exceeded for x.x.x.x (But here's the good news: Authenticated requests get a higher rate limit. Check out the documentation for more details.)","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api#rate-limiting"}`

Comment: found the limit in the response headers: `x-ratelimit-limit: 60`

Comment: 23-05-13 it work,  but it is api.github.com/user/<id>  ,no colon

Comment: Alternatively, if you install the [Github CLI client](https://github.com/cli/cli), you can use the command line — for example, you can get my public details with `gh api /user/376642 --method GET`

Answer (score 8):

There's no documented feature, nor undocumented ones that I know of, that expose the retrieval of the username from the id. From the GitHub API consumer perspective, the user id is an "implementation detail". The real key is the username.

From what I understand, you only require a batch of usernames given a list of ids. And this would be a one time only request, not a permanent need.

As your request seems legit and limited in its scope, you might get this answer directly from GitHub support by dropping them an email at support@github.com.

Indeed, **xpaulbettsx**, a GitHubber, even **[tweeted about this](https://twitter.com/xpaulbettsx/status/221070164056211456)**:

> Support@ is good for Anything you want to tell GitHub - bugs, features, high 5s; everything but security which go to security@

Comment: well even though the user name is the "real key" it can change, which may be problematic.

Answer (score 4):

The answer marked correct here doesn't work anymore. You'll now get

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/users#get-a-user"
}
```

Now do a Direct Node Lookup via Graphql
https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/guides/using-global-node-ids#3-do-a-direct-node-lookup-in-graphql

Answer (score 0):

There is actually an official, documented endpoint that lets you do this: the endpoint to *list* users, [`/users`](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/users/users?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-users).

It accepts two parameters you can use to get a specific user ID:

- `since` - integer, users with IDs greater than this will be returned in order
- `per_page` - limit number of results per page

So given a user id `USER_ID`, you can  make a request with `since = USER_ID - 1` and `per_page = 1` to get a specific user.

For example, to look up `USER_ID = 1000`, you set `since=999` like this:

```bash
; curl 'https://api.github.com/users?since=999&per_page=1'
[
  {
    "login": "aslakhellesoy",
    "id": 1000,
    ⋮ snip
    "site_admin": false
  }
]
```

Answer (score -2):

By the time I answer this question, the method that works is:
https://api.github.com/user/USER_ID

Remark: It is similar to what Andrew shared in 2015; you just have to remove the colon in the URL he shared.

Comment: just in case you're not aware yet `:id` represents a url parameter variable, some uses `{id}`, so you just need to replace the whole thing with the actual id