# Where can I find the GitHub ID in my account?

Tags: github

What is the difference between GitHub username and GitHub ID? I was asked for my Github ID for a certain project and I happened to give my username. But the person is unable to find me on GitHub with my username. So I got a GitHub ID from the below URL:

http://caius.github.io/github_id/

But I'm unable to find this ID from my account directly. Where can I find this in my GitHub account? It would be great to elaborate on this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get github username by id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976393/get-github-username-by-id)

Answer (score 176, accepted):

It can be easily retrieved using GitHub API:

```
https://api.github.com/users/your_github_user_name
```

where instead of ***your_github_user_name*** you must use the desired GitHub *username*.

---

*Example:*
https://api.github.com/users/github

Comment: Note: No trailing slash, gives a confusing 404 :)

Comment: they just hit 100 million users, I'm #12,835,202.

Answer (score 41):

It can be easily retrieved using Github API.

Example: https://api.github.com/users/username

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It can be easily retrieved using `Github API`. If you cannot use the API answer or from http://caius.github.io/github_id/ you can go to `github --> settings --> emails` , under the Primary email address you will find `{id}+{user_name}@users.noreply.github.com`. The format is simillar to this: `50826640+hirwablessing@users.noreply.github.com`, that `50826640` is the `id`.

Answer (score 3):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65574986/4294399)

> If you cannot use [the API answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17309026/4759619) or from http://caius.github.io/github_id/ you can go to `github --> settings --> emails`, under the `Primary email address` you will find `{id}+{user_name}@users.noreply.github.com`.

This is at least true if you have `Keep my email address private` checked.
I have this text in the `Keep my email address private` explanation, and I'm guessing this will be there even if it is turned off.

Look for 'noreply' in the emails section.

Answer (score 3):

From the command line:

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/users/<your-user-name> | jq '.id'
```

Answer (score 1):

**Step-1:**  Go to this link:
https://caius.github.io/github_id/

**Step-2** Enter your Github username

**You got it!**

*The second method is:*

1. Go to your GitHub account and click on the Settings option.
2. Go to the emails section.
3. You id is listed there. The format is:
   {id}+{user_name}@users.noreply.github.com

Comment: This is the same link as in the question...

Comment: Yeah and this totally works. also, I have also listed another method to verify the id!

Comment: @EricAya is saying you missed the point of the question, which explicitly asks, "Where can I find this in my GitHub account?"

Answer (score 1):

If you do have the GitHub Id but need to find the username / login you can do it like this with the List users endpoint:

Subtract the id by 1 and run the following query. My GitHub Id is `4015237` and therefore the query parameter since receives the value `4015236`.

https://api.github.com/users?since=4015236&per_page=1

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/users/users?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-users

Description for since:

> Query parameters - since - A user ID. Only return users with an ID
> greater than this ID.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Only this method is working,

1. Go to your GitHub account and click on the Settings option.
2. Go to the emails section.Your id is listed there.
3. The format is:

   {id}+{user_name}@users.noreply.github.com

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

Don't use the ID stated in other answers I tried this and it didn't work and said it was invalid on AWS.

It's located on the main GIT repository. Those random letters and numbers are below the add file button with no description, obviously.  Not only that but it's clickable if you click into it you'll find a much longer commit ID. You want the longer one.

Everyone loves completely unnecessary complexity in a platform!!

Comment: I believe that you're confusing the GitHub ID with the Commit ID (which, indeed, has both a short and a long version). However, these two things are unrelated to each other. The GitHub ID is basically the ID for your username, nothing else. A commit ID represents a set of changes committed at a certain time by a user, _to a specific repository_ — I don't know what you consider the 'main GIT repository', but all repositories have commits, and each commit has a (unique) commit ID. A single GitHub user can have zillions of commits — all with a unique ID — spread across trillions of repositories.

Comment: So basically I was on AWS's code deploy and it asked for the Github ID.  Only the long commit ID worked. So I've put this here as people with a similar issue will be able to get the job done.  The main repo being the root of the repo you want to use btw.

Answer (score -1):

You can find your GitHub ID on https://github.com/settings/emails.