# How get image by cid imap email using mailso library https://github.com/INTELOGIE/MailSo

Tags: php, html-email, mail-server

I am using [MailSo](https://github.com/INTELOGIE/MailSo) like this:

```
$this->MailClient()->Message($folder, (int)$index);
```

I have an image in the email body with this type:

```
<img style="width: 100%" src="cid:csimg0.jpg" />
```

How do I get the real source of this image?

Comment: actually that is the real source of your image. they are stored in the emails attachment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find the GitHub ID in my account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308954/where-can-i-find-the-github-id-in-my-account)

Comment: but I have incorrect path http://joxi.ru/EA4ZgExiDEqxbm