# Is GitHub id an unchangeable identifier?

Tags: github, github-api

[Where can I find the GitHub ID in my account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308954/where-can-i-find-the-github-id-in-my-account/40695228)

GitHub username is changeable. is GitHub id unchangeable?

Not mentioned in https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/users#get-contextual-information-for-a-user

Comment: GitHub ID is unchangeable because that is used as a unique identifier for each user.

Comment: @Theepag source?

Comment: No source is stating that, but I guess without that GH couldn't uniquely identify each users

Answer (score 0):

Done some digging, here's what I've found:
Tried to change my user name: user id was unchanged.
In [this](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/managing-user-account-settings/changing-your-github-username#your-git-commits) and [this](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/managing-email-preferences/setting-your-commit-email-address) documentations it looks like you no-replay email (which is contracted from your id) does not change.
[This](https://github.community/t/go-back-to-non-id-based-noreply-email/141872) answer supports this as well.
As does [this](https://github.community/t/go-back-to-non-id-based-noreply-email/141872) api call doc ("since" query parameter explenation).

So, no direct quote in documentation, but close.
If you've found something since then I'd like to hear it.