# Get github username by Github User ID

Tags: github

Is there a good way of getting the username and info for the ID in github?

Using ID I can currently get the avatar, but not any other user information.

eg:
https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/2015

I have checked a similar question: [Get github username by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976393/get-github-username-by-id)

But the suggested answer does't seem to work any longer.

https://api.github.com/user/:2014 returns nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your problem is quite a bit easy. You just missed few facts. I am clearing these for you ,

- You have to check the [GITHUB API V3](https://developer.github.com/v3/) - for a grasp on how these api really works. which is helpful for future projects.
- And please also the `https://api.github.com/user/:2014` is used slightly wrong way. You see , you have to use it as `https://api.github.com/user/2014` this way . In my case it is providing ,

  `{
    "login": "lee",
    "id": 2014,
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/2014?v=3",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/lee",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/lee",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/lee/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/lee/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/lee/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/lee/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/lee/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/lee/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/lee/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/lee/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/lee/received_events",
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": false,
    "name": null,
    "company": null,
    "blog": null,
    "location": "New York, NY",
    "email": null,
    "hireable": null,
    "bio": null,
    "public_repos": 6,
    "public_gists": 7,
    "followers": 16,
    "following": 7,
    "created_at": "2008-03-03T14:23:14Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-02-26T22:34:45Z"
  }`

---

so , I think this will solve the problem and wish you a great day . :)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking to do this using the GitHub v4 GraphQL API, here's how you do it:

```
{
  node (id: "INSERT USERID") {
    ... on User {
      id
      login
    }
  }
}
```

The `... on User` lets you look up attributes specific to `User` objects since a `Node` could be any number of things (e.g. users, repos, commits). See an [official answer by GitHub on their forum](https://github.community/t/official-support-for-looking-up-resources-by-id/119703/2) for more details.