# How to list users who have not setup their display names in GITHUB using github api?

Tags: github-api

How to list users who have not setup their display names in GITHUB using  github api ?

I have tried watching many videos on YouTube and have also gone through many docs and blogs but I didn't find anything relevant to it.

I have also seen `github api` official docs and I found it to be advanced for my level of understanding.

So Can you please help me here ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is in the [GitHub API documents](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/users). If they don't have a username/login, you can just reference the id. If that's what you want, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976393/get-github-username-by-id) is the answer.

Access the API via: `https://api.github.com/user/:id` instead, and replace `id` with the id number

EDIT: That API is no longer working.

As far as I can see, you have to provide the username.

Otherwise, [this](https://github.community/t/official-support-for-looking-up-resources-by-id/119703/2) may be what you are looking for.